# Filter Data for clustering

Tags: clustering

I am trying to synthetize clients Data in order to do clustering. **My problem is for 1 customer I have severals rows**. I would like to synthetize informations to get 1 row per customer. This clustering is about how customers use fidelity program. Here is a picture of my table : By Column (left to right) :

*1) CustomerID 2)Date at which their use their points 3) Category number (Ex: 1 is gift card, 2 is a flight etc) 4) How many points they used 5) How many items they purchased with points*
[image: Table]

My question is how could I have 1 customer per row without loosing informations.
Maybe Pivot Table? But I don"t know how it work exactly. I am new to statistic btw.

Thank you

Cédric

Comment: Why do you want to throw away information? Can't you cluster users as is; e.g., by modeling each user as a vector of points per category?

Comment: I have 3 others tables with customer and I have to join them together.
If I have for the table 1 5 times customer 1500 and for the table 2 26 times the customer 1400 I can"t join my 2 tables ?

Comment: From a machine learning perspective, that is no problem. Is it feasible to do this join even once?

Comment: Yes only once. But maybe I should do : 1 Column per category for example.  I would know if a customer use more points in category 1 than 5. Then when i will do the clustering process an customers who spend a lot of points in "Gift card" will be together ?This is why I should use pivot table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford to do the full join once, do it and learn which columns are useful through [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection). Then you can only SELECT these columns for subsequent iterations, when the database is updated.

Here's a survey: [Feature Selection for Clustering: A Review](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.8115&rep=rep1&type=pdf)